# How to reinstall Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I recently upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS. Since then Thunderbird has been adding strange images to the email list window.

[image: Thunderbird Image]

How would I go about reinstalling Thunderbird while maintaining the email account settings that are already added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Thunderbird issue seems to be due to a missing dependency that allows printing emojis.

> sudo apt install fonts-symbola

That should fix the issue.